# How do I set an initial value for a foreignkey on a model based form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to set an initial value for a foreignkey named "Customer" in my model based form named "LocationForm" using `form = LocationForm(initial={'customer':Customer.objects.get(id=1)})` but the form is failing validation.

I am hiding this input with a widget in my forms.py file, so I tested enabling the input and selecting the "Customer" manually in the form and it passes validation.  What am I doing wrong when I'm trying to set the initial value?

```
#views.py
def add_location(request):
if request.POST:
    form = LocationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/django/location')
else:
    form = LocationForm(initial={'customer':Customer.objects.get(id=1)})

return render(request, 'add_location.html', {'form': form})


#forms.py
class LocationForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Location
    widgets = {'customer': forms.HiddenInput}


#models.py
class Customer(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
...

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

class Location(models.Model):
customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
...

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

**UPDATE:**
I figured out what the problem was.  Even if you specify that one of the fields is a HiddenInput in forms.py, you still need to include the tags for the form in the template.  I included the following in my add_location.html file and it works now:

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.customer.errors }}
    {{ form.customer }}
</div>
```

I should note that I was doing a custom form template instead of doing the generic {{form.as_p}}.  If I had done it that way I believe it would have worked.  I suppose there's no actual reason to do the hiddeninput when doing a custom form template.

Comment: Does a customer with the id=1 exist?

Comment: Let's see the form code.

Comment: Forms.py and models.py have been added to the original post.  Customer with id=1 does exist, if I run Customer.objects.get(id=1) in shell it returns <Customer: Foo>

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude hiddenfield from form and populate that field before you start saving object:

## forms.py

```
class LocationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        exclude = ('customer',)
```

## views.py

```
def add_location(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = LocationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
        entry = form.save(commit=False)
        entry.customer = Customer.objects.get(id=1)
        entry.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/django/location')
    else:
        form = LocationForm()

    return render(request, 'add_location.html', {'form': form})
```